# Syntax error in resource file. I don't understand

Tags: c++, syntax, resources, singleton

I have a .rc file:

```
#include "MainWindowResource.h"

MAINWINDOW_MENU MENU DISCARDABLE
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
        BEGIN
            MENUITEM "&New\tCtrl+N",                    MAINWINDOW_MENU_FILE_NEW
            MENUITEM "&Open\tCtrl+O",                   MAINWINDOW_MENU_FILE_OPEN
            MENUITEM "&Save\tCtrl+S",                   MAINWINDOW_MENU_FILE_SAVE
            MENUITEM "&Save As\tCtrl+Shift+S",          MAINWINDOW_MENU_FILE_SAVEAS

            MENUITEM SEPARATOR

            MENUITEM "&Print\tCtrl+P",                  MAINWINDOW_MENU_FILE_PRINT
            MENUITEM "Print Pre&view\tCtrl+Shift+P",    MAINWINDOW_MENU_FILE_PRINTPREVIEW

            MENUITEM SEPARATOR

            MENUITEM "E&xit\tAlt+F4",                   MAINWINDOW_MENU_FILE_EXIT
        END
    POPUP "&Edit"

    POPUP "&View"

    POPUP "&Tools"

    POPUP "&Help"
END
```

Now my compiler (MinGW) says this:

```
C:\DOCUME~1\RADEKS~1\BUREAU~1\C__~1\LIQUID~1\MAINWI~1.RC|23|syntax error|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Line 23 is this line:

```
    POPUP "&View"
```

I don't understand what's wrong with my code. Can anyone help me plz?

Thanks.

Comment: For completeness sake, this should probably be tagged with the platform it targets (Windows? Qt? Gtk?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `MAINWINDOW_FILE_EXIT` defined to be?  You might find it has some bogus text as part of its definition, or a missing quote if it's a string.

**Edit**: You probably need `BEGIN` and `END` even for an empty `POPUP`.

Comment: I solved that part. It's an int typo. My problem is other now.